# Extract XML Node data SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to extract XML node from SQL query. I have XML report specification in one of the column of SQL table.

I want to extract sqlText node from the XML using SQL query.

I have uploaded the xml to dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/28xu7ifu78h6gm0/AACQS24NEjPFO0GXEI9vLuefa?dl=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xml document

```
declare @xml xml ='<report ....</report>'
select @xml.value('(/report/queries/query/source/sqlQuery/sqlText)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [SqlText]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XML data is stored in XML typed column named `myXmlColumn` in SQL table named `myTable`, you can specify the default namespace for the XPath using [`;WITH  XMLNAMESPACES()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx), for example :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(default 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/8.0/')
select myTable.myXmlColumn.value('(/report/queries/query/source/sqlQuery/sqlText)[1]'
                                 , 'varchar(max)') as sqlText
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one sqlQuery node, following [SQL XML query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-xml-query-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) can be used

```
SELECT
  [Query].value('.','varchar(100)') AS QueryText
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/queries/query/source/sqlQuery/sqlText') Queries([Query])
```